# remove whitespace and change order of subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a plot like this:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

a1 = [1.9, 1.8, 1.5, 1.4]
a1_x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

a2 = [2.5, 2.3, 2.2, 2.1]
a2_x = ["q", "w", "e", "r"]

a3 = [4.9, 4.8, 4.6, 4.5]
a3_x = ["x", "c", "v", "b"]

pos = np.arange(4)

f, ((ax1, ax2, ax3)) = plt.subplots(3, 1, figsize=(8, 5))
ax1.barh(pos, a1, align='center')
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(4))
ax1.set_yticklabels(a1_x, minor=False)
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
f.gca().invert_yaxis()

ax2.barh(pos, a2, align='center')
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(4))
ax2.set_yticklabels(a2_x, minor=False)
ax2.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
f.gca().invert_yaxis()

ax3.barh(pos, a3, align='center')
ax3.set_yticks(np.arange(4))
ax3.set_yticklabels(a3_x, minor=False)
ax3.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)

f.gca().invert_yaxis()
f.tight_layout()
```

[image]

How can I remove the whitespace of each subplot and also flip the order of the first two plots. `f.gca().invert_yaxis()` only works for the third plot.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust for whitesapce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated, if you change the amount of y-ticks, you'll be able to get rid of the 'whitespaces'. Also, the [`gca()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.gca) method **g**ets the **c**urrent **a**xes, which in your case is always the last one. To invert every axes, explicitly tell each one to. Example for one axes:

```
[...]
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(a1_x)))
ax1.set_yticklabels(a1_x, minor=False)
ax1.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax1.invert_yaxis()
[...]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a `matplotlib.pyplot`-native solution, and thus not the right solution, but what occurs for the first two plots if instead of the following lines (exemple with `a1`-related objects, but it would be the same for `a2`-related ones)

```
...
ax1.barh(pos, a1, align='center')
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(10))
ax1.set_yticklabels(a1_x, minor=False)
...
```

you write

```
...
ax1.barh(pos, a1[::-1], align='center')
ax1.set_yticks(np.arange(len(a1)))
ax1.set_yticklabels(a1_x[::-1], minor=False)
```